# Ubuntu 12.04, 2 NVIDIA GPUs, 2 different XScreens

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, ubuntu-12.04

I have two separate GPUs on my desktop, each has one monitor attached with.

I know Compiz does not work with Xinerama, and TwinView only works when 2 monitors are from the same GPU. So I disable both and use `nvidia-settings` to get my second monitor working.

Now I have one monitor that displays my unity desktop correctly.

On the other monitor I can use my mouse, right click, create folder etc... but there is no window management (so I can't change desktop, can't close a opened window ..)

Is there anyway to have Unity, or any window management, working on the second monitor?